# Building/porting libraries to Native Client projects

Tags: python, c++, build, cygwin, google-nativeclient

I am trying to rework an existing c++ project so that it will build with the NaCl SDK, and I need to link a few libraries so that the revised project will properly compile. I am still in the "getting started" tutorial phase of figuring things out, and so I have thus far only altered the basic .cc project file and the corresponding Makefile to add support for jsoncpp... but now I am absolutely stuck trying to sort out porting some of the other libraries into the project. In particular, I am trying to add curl and opencv, but I would like to learn the basics of this procedure so that it will not take me several days to do this again next time.

I have been using this page as my main reference: https://chromium.googlesource.com/webports/+/master/README.md. Because I usually only work in Visual Studio and tend to use the same libraries, I don't often get into command line stuff or cygwin, etc... so I was immediately lost when I got into this. Apologies in advance, but my head is mush after looking at it for the last couple of days.

Anyway, I have cloned all of the libraries from webports git, so I'm pretty sure I have all of the files needed to build them (i.e. a ton of directories with "pkg_info", "build.sh" and "nacl.patch"). And I have cygwin up and running, though I am still unclear as to 1) if I have environment variable correctly set and 2) if I have installed cywin with all that is needed to run the commands in the "build.sh" scripts, etc.

As a test, even though I am not using it for this project, I have been trying to link "openssl" in order to follow the example. I have configured and synced gclient so that I end up with a new "src" directory in the "webports" directory, and the I have entered the following in the cygwin console:

```
 $ cd src
 # NACL_ARCH=arm make openssl
```

which came back with this message:

```
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
```

After trying dozens of variations I finally tried this command from the example:

```
 $ ./webports/make_all.sh openssl
```

which came back with the slightly more exciting but still unsuccessful message:

```
 + set -e
 + TARGETS=openssl
 + TARGETS=openssl
 + BUILD_FLAGS=--ignore-disabled
 + export BUILD_FLAGS
 + NACL_ARCH=x86_64
 + TOOLCHAIN=clang-newlib
 + make openssl
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
 + NACL_ARCH=x86_64
 + TOOLCHAIN=glibc
 + make openssl
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
 + NACL_ARCH=i686
 + TOOLCHAIN=clang-newlib
 + make openssl
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
 + NACL_ARCH=i686
 + TOOLCHAIN=glibc
 + make openssl
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
 + NACL_ARCH=arm
 + TOOLCHAIN=clang-newlib
 + make openssl
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
 + NACL_ARCH=arm
 + TOOLCHAIN=glibc
 + make openssl
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
 + NACL_ARCH=le32
 + TOOLCHAIN=pnacl
 + make openssl
 make: Nothing to be done for 'openssl'.
 + '[' -n '' ']'
```

So yeah, I am clearly missing some part of the process here, but the documentation is really not helping me figure out what that is. Any nudge in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

EDIT:

After a lot of frustration trying to decipher the various warnings and error messages, I decided to completely uninstall cygwin and reinstall it with as many of the packages as I could find that seemed to be related to git, make, python, etc. - which took forever. Then I deleted all of the previous nacl_sdk files and started over from scratch. That seems to have cleared up most of the warnings, but the builds still fail.

When syncing gclient with the branch heads, I still get a few warnings or notices (such as "byte-compiling is disabled"), though it looks as if most of these are due to specific instructions buried in the new "src" files. I do also get a weird notice that I am using subversion instead of git (even though git is installed), but that does not seem to cause any problems either.

Anyway, after the sync has finished I set the NACL_SDK_ROOT environment variable and change the directory:

```
 $ export NACL_SDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/pepper_49
 $ cd src
```

and proceed with the build:

```
 $ NACL_ARCH=le32 TOOLCHAIN=pnacl make openssl
 bin/webports install openssl
 Building 'gtest' [le32/pnacl/release]
 Mirroring upstream git repo: https://github.com/google/googletest.git@6f8a664
 git clone --mirror https://github.com/google/googletest.git github.com_google_googletest.git
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
     exec code in run_globals
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/__main__.py", line 385, in <module>
     sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/__main__.py", line 371, in main
     run_main(args)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/__main__.py", line 366, in run_main
     do_cmd(p)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/__main__.py", line 342, in do_cmd
     pkg_commands[args.command](package, args)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/__main__.py", line 173, in cmd_pkg_install
     from_source=options.from_source)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 267, in install
     self.install_deps(force, from_source)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 223, in install_deps
     dep.install(True, force, from_source)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 267, in install
     self.install_deps(force, from_source)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 223, in install_deps
     dep.install(True, force, from_source)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 281, in install
     self.build(build_deps, force)
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 358, in build
     self.download()
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 397, in download
     self.git_clone_to_mirror()
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 627, in git_clone_to_mirror
     run_git_cmd(paths.CACHE_ROOT, ['clone', '--mirror', git_url, git_mirror])
   File "/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/lib/webports/source_package.py", line 87, in run_git_cmd
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/cygdrive/c/Users/mimewear/Desktop/nacl_sdk/webports/src/out/cache'
 make: *** [Makefile:89: openssl] Error 1
```

This is progress, but I cannot make sense of this final error message. The "webports/src/out/cache" directory does not exists, and it looks like it is not being created when the "src" directory is being synced with gclient or when openssl is attempting to build. I can also see where the exception is being thrown at line 1335 in "subprocess.py", and if I do create the "cache" directory at the correct location and try again the build does nudge a little further before throwing the same exception (but this time without a reference to the missing file/directory).

At this point I can only think that I am missing some portion of a repository or something?? Seriously, WTF?? Learning a ton about things I really am not sure I wanted to know about.

So close though (I hope).

Comment: why do you think `NACL_ARCH=arm` could work ?

Comment: Yeah, I know I don't really need to compile all of the available architectures... I was just getting to the point where I wanted to get at least something to compile, and the example seemed like a good place to start. I suppose I have made a bit of progress since posting this though: I think there was a problem with the make or python packages (or both) in my cygwin installation, and so gclient was giving me various errors as it synced with "webports.git". After reinstalling cygwin with all of the required tools, I can finally see some movement in the right direction but still no success.